# error: conflicting types for 'indata_1d'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to synthesise this codes with the c-to-verilog tool. I have made the necessary changes such as: remove the printf, change the 2d array of indata to 1d. However I am getting this message when I try to synthesize it.

```
/file589:1114: error: conflicting types for 'indata_1d'
/file589:1113: error: previous declaration of 'indata_1d' was here
/file589:1114: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
/file589:1114: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
/file589:1114: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
```

these are my codes. I am not sure if I made the right changes

```
#ifndef SHA_H
#define SHA_H

/* NIST Secure Hash Algorithm */
/* heavily modified from Peter C. Gutmann's implementation */

/* Useful defines & typedefs */

 typedef unsigned char BYTE;
 typedef unsigned int INT32;

 #define SHA_BLOCKSIZE 64

INT32 sha_info_digest[5];   /* message digest */
INT32 sha_info_count_lo, sha_info_count_hi; /* 64-bit bit count */
INT32 sha_info_data[16];

void sha_init ();
void sha_update (const BYTE *, int);
void sha_final ();

void sha_stream ();
void sha_print ();

#define BLOCK_SIZE 8192
#define VSIZE 2

const BYTE indata[VSIZE][BLOCK_SIZE] = {
{75, 117, 114, 116, 86, 111, 110, 110, 101, 103, 117, 116, 115, 67, 111,
109, 109, 101, 110, 99, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 65, 100, 100, 114, 101,
115, 115, 97, 116, 77, 73, 84, 76, 97, 100, 105, 101, 115, 97, 110, 100,
103, 101, 110, 116, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 111, 102, 116, 104, 101, 99,
108, 97, 115, 115, 111, 102, 57, 55, 87, 101, 97, 114, 115, 117, 110, 115,
99, 114, 101, 101, 110, 73, 102, 73, 99, 111, 117, 108, 100, 111, 102, 102,
101, 114, 121, 111, 117, 111, 110, 108, 121, 111, 110, 101, 116, 105, 112,
102, 111, 114, 116, 104, 101, 102, 117, 116, 117, 114, 101, 115, 117, 110,
115, 99, 114, 101, 101, 110, 119, 111, 117, 108, 100, 98, 101, 105, 116,
84, 104, 101, 108, 111, 110, 103, 116, 101, 114, 109, 98, 101, 110, 101,
102, 105, 116, 115, 111, 102, 115, 117, 110, 115, 99, 114, 101, 101, 110,
104, 97, 118, 101, 98, 101, 101, 110, 112, 114, 111, 118, 101, 100, 98,
121, 115, 99, 105, 101, 110, 116, 105, 115, 116, 115, 119, 104, 101, 114,
101, 97, 115, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 115, 116, 111, 102, 109, 121, 97,
100, 118, 105, 99, 101, 104, 97, 115, 110, 111, 98, 97, 115, 105, 115, 109, ....
} 
}; //exceeded the limit of characters to put here

const BYTE *indata_1d;
indata_1d = indata;
const int in_i[VSIZE] = { 8192, 8192 };
#endif /* SHA_H */

/* SHA f()-functions */
#define f1(x,y,z)   ((x & y) | (~x & z))
#define f2(x,y,z)   (x ^ y ^ z)
#define f3(x,y,z)   ((x & y) | (x & z) | (y & z))
#define f4(x,y,z)   (x ^ y ^ z)

/* SHA constants */
#define CONST1      0x5a827999L
#define CONST2      0x6ed9eba1L
#define CONST3      0x8f1bbcdcL
#define CONST4      0xca62c1d6L

/* 32-bit rotate */

#define ROT32(x,n)  ((x << n) | (x >> (32 - n)))

#define FUNC(n,i)                       \
temp = ROT32(A,5) + f##n(B,C,D) + E + W[i] + CONST##n;  \
E = D; D = C; C = ROT32(B,30); B = A; A = temp

/* compute the SHA digest of a FILE stream */
void sha_stream ()
{
int i, j;
const BYTE **p;

sha_init ();
for (j = 0; j < VSIZE; j++)
{
  i = in_i[j];
  p = &indata_1d[j*BLOCK_SIZE + 0];
  sha_update (p, i);
}
sha_final ();
}

void local_memset (INT32 * s, int c, int n, int e)
{
INT32 uc;
INT32 *p;
int m;

m = n / 4;
uc = c;
p = (INT32 *) s;
while (e-- > 0)
{
  p++;
}
while (m-- > 0)
{
  *p++ = uc;
}
}

void local_memcpy (INT32 * s1, const BYTE * s2, int n)
{
INT32 *p1;
BYTE *p2;
INT32 tmp;
int m;
m = n / 4;
p1 = (INT32 *) s1;
p2 = (BYTE *) s2;

while (m-- > 0)
{
  tmp = 0;
  tmp |= 0xFF & *p2++;
  tmp |= (0xFF & *p2++) << 8;
  tmp |= (0xFF & *p2++) << 16;
  tmp |= (0xFF & *p2++) << 24;
  *p1 = tmp;
  p1++;
}
}

/* do SHA transformation */
static void sha_transform ()
{
int i;
INT32 temp, A, B, C, D, E, W[80];

for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
  W[i] = sha_info_data[i];
}
for (i = 16; i < 80; ++i)
{
  W[i] = W[i - 3] ^ W[i - 8] ^ W[i - 14] ^ W[i - 16];
}
A = sha_info_digest[0];
B = sha_info_digest[1];
C = sha_info_digest[2];
D = sha_info_digest[3];
E = sha_info_digest[4];

for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
  FUNC (1, i);
}
for (i = 20; i < 40; ++i)
{
  FUNC (2, i);
}
for (i = 40; i < 60; ++i)
{
  FUNC (3, i);
}
for (i = 60; i < 80; ++i)
{
  FUNC (4, i);
}

sha_info_digest[0] += A;
sha_info_digest[1] += B;
sha_info_digest[2] += C;
sha_info_digest[3] += D;
sha_info_digest[4] += E;
}

/* initialize the SHA digest */

void sha_init ()
{
sha_info_digest[0] = 0x67452301L;
sha_info_digest[1] = 0xefcdab89L;
sha_info_digest[2] = 0x98badcfeL;
sha_info_digest[3] = 0x10325476L;
sha_info_digest[4] = 0xc3d2e1f0L;
sha_info_count_lo = 0L;
sha_info_count_hi = 0L;
}

/* update the SHA digest */

void sha_update (const BYTE * buffer, int count)
{
if ((sha_info_count_lo + ((INT32) count << 3)) < sha_info_count_lo)
{
  ++sha_info_count_hi;
}
sha_info_count_lo += (INT32) count << 3;
sha_info_count_hi += (INT32) count >> 29;
while (count >= SHA_BLOCKSIZE)
{
  local_memcpy (sha_info_data, buffer, SHA_BLOCKSIZE);
  sha_transform ();
  buffer += SHA_BLOCKSIZE;
  count -= SHA_BLOCKSIZE;
}
local_memcpy (sha_info_data, buffer, count);
}

/* finish computing the SHA digest */

void sha_final ()
{
int count;
INT32 lo_bit_count;
INT32 hi_bit_count;

lo_bit_count = sha_info_count_lo;
hi_bit_count = sha_info_count_hi;
count = (int) ((lo_bit_count >> 3) & 0x3f);
sha_info_data[count++] = 0x80;
if (count > 56)
{
  local_memset (sha_info_data, 0, 64 - count, count);
  sha_transform ();
  local_memset (sha_info_data, 0, 56, 0);
}
else
{
  local_memset (sha_info_data, 0, 56 - count, count);
}
sha_info_data[14] = hi_bit_count;
sha_info_data[15] = lo_bit_count;
sha_transform ();
}

const INT32 outData[5] =
{0x006a5a37UL, 0x93dc9485UL, 0x2c412112UL, 0x63f7ba43UL, 0xad73f922UL };

int main ()
{
int i;
int main_result;
  main_result = 0;
  sha_stream ();

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

  main_result += (sha_info_digest[i] != outData[i]);
}

  return main_result;
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: @Zaibis there is no need to review all 250 lines of the code. I posted so that anyone who can help me can have a rough idea of what I am trying to do. And in case you haven't notice, most of the lines of codes are just constant char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want use   two-dimensional arry for an one-dimensional
  so use the below code maybe help

```
const BYTE *indata_1d = indata[0]; //indata is two-dimensional 
                                   //I think maybe you want use the first array
    //indata_1d = indata;
```

and the function below should be corrected

```
/* compute the SHA digest of a FILE stream */
    void sha_stream()
    {
        int i, j;
        const BYTE *p;                             //one-dimensional array

        sha_init();
        for (j = 0; j < VSIZE; j++)
        {
            i = in_i[j];
            p = &indata_1d[j*BLOCK_SIZE + 0];  //indata_1d is one-dimensional array
            sha_update(p, i);
        }
        sha_final();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
indata_1d = indata;
```

This is not allowed

```
const BYTE *indata_1d = indata ;
```

Gives a warning, but the first version is not valid C